# Copy paste character limits between Access and Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I'm trying to copy-paste a query result from Access 2007 to Excel 2007 but some text columns that appear OK in Access are "cut-off" when pasting to Excel.

How to paste this correctly, avoiding the limit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3rd party & better clipboard manager since MS Office's clipboard manager has limitations. I recommend [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Tried that, seems to have the same problem. Copy-pasting to Word seems to work (but data is unreadable)

Comment: Damn, I thought it's a clipboard problem... Anyway, giving an eye to [this MS page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/exchange-copy-import-export-data-between-excel-and-access-HA010096300.aspx) can help, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has some quirks with copy & paste to maintain backwards compatibility with very older versions.